# Create 3 3D arrays from 3 1D arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I would like to find a way to mimic MATLAB's ndarray in Python (very different ndarry function!)

so if I have 3 1D arrays, say i = 0:10, j = 0:11, k = 0:12, I would like to create 3 3D arrays,
I, J and K are all 3D array of size(11, 12, 13) with their values given by:

I(x,:,:) = i(x), J(:,x,:) = j(x) and K(:,:,x) = k(x)

In MATLAB this is simply:

[I, J, K] = ndarray(i,j,k)

is there something similar in Python, without reverting to loops - I can't seem to find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`numpy.meshgrid` does what you want

```py
import numpy as np
I,J,K = np.meshgrid(range(2), range(3), range(4))

In [17]: print(f'I={I}')                                                                                                                                                                                    
I=[[[0 0 0 0]
  [1 1 1 1]]

 [[0 0 0 0]
  [1 1 1 1]]

 [[0 0 0 0]
  [1 1 1 1]]]

In [19]: print(f'J={J}')                                                                                                                                                                                    
J=[[[0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0]]

 [[1 1 1 1]
  [1 1 1 1]]

 [[2 2 2 2]
  [2 2 2 2]]]

In [20]: print(f'K={K}')                                                                                                                                                                                    
K=[[[0 1 2 3]
  [0 1 2 3]]

 [[0 1 2 3]
  [0 1 2 3]]

 [[0 1 2 3]
  [0 1 2 3]]]
```

or equivalently, the slightly more elegant `mgrid`:

```
I, J, K = np.mgrid[0:2,0:3,0:4]
```

Comment: Brilliant, knew there must be some way, thanks!